# 1.9: Home Page Content Gone

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I have suddenly noticed that all of the content (Which is in a static CMS page) on my home page has disappeared.

I can see the Header/Footer sections, and I can see from the HTML (The body class) that the corect page is being loaded, but none of it's content shows. It seems that even if I switch the page that's set as home, or preview it, nothing shows.

I haven't edited that part of the site for 3+ months, and certainly didn't change anything to affect it. I haven't updated any extensions either, as this *was* a live and stable site. Products are working correctly, and no error is showing anywhere.

Things I have tried:

- Tested on 3 devices/browsers
- Cleared all caches, browser and magento
- Checked the right static block is being called
- Checked that the Static Block has the content inside
- Checked the code, nothing is being inserted into the `main-container` div apart from a little snippet of cart js that also appears in the correct version, it's not simply CSS hidden or anything
- Rebooted the Ubuntu Server.

**EDIT**: It seems that if a customer logs in, then the home page displays correctly.

Comment: Is your other cms pages are showing content???

Comment: @AsishHira I don't have any other CMS pages at present.

Comment: What is the layout of your homepage??

Comment: @AsishHira It's a custom theme. It is 1 column, though.

Comment: in 1column.phtml check `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>` code is there or not

Comment: @AsishHira It is there

Comment: can you able to provide me the link of your website

Comment: @AsishHira I'd rather not on the public internet, if that's OK.  Is there another way to get it to you?

Comment: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: I'm afraid it's not on localhost, or even on my LAN, it's a VPS.

Comment: Your hompage contain any block code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect element and see that is there is something error or **tag** ending is missing or not

Comment: I have just re-done that. No content from the CMS page appears at all, just the container that it would usually be in. It seems that if a customer logs in, then the home page displays correctly.

Comment: Then you need to check all of extension which are being used right now on your store. There must have some observer which is preventing guest users to view homepage

Comment: There is a customer prices extension that includes the option to hide/show products, but I can't think of anything else. I didn't change any options :P Will update with what I find.

Comment: ok.  In my case i had find a extension.

Comment: I can't find anything. However I can see some strange bug where come CMS pages will not load, in a very similar manner to the home page. Even ones I don't use. If I duplicate the page, it won't work, however if I change the content to a simple `<h1>TEST</h1>` it does work!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue.

On my Home Page there was a block of code like so:

`<div id="new_products" class="type1">{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" hover_effect="alternative" product_count="8" template="filterproducts/owl_list.phtml"}}</div>`

This of course showed the latest added products. I had recently added 3 products, so I disabled them, and boom the site loaded. I then enabled them one by one until I found the culprit.

I can see no particular attribute on this product that could cause this bug, but it caused the issue nontheless. I changed every single product attribute but that didn't change anything.

Simply deleting and readding the product fixed the issue.